# Cannot reinstall Windows 10 using Windows 8.1 product key even though I upgraded last year free from 8.1 to 10?

Tags: windows-10, windows-8.1, windows-10-upgrade

Last year I upgraded my Windows 8.1 license to Windows 10 via the free upgrade programme.

Yesterday I needed to reinstall Windows 10. I booted into the USB to install and I entered my Windows 8.1 product key, and it says my key is not accepted.

This is on exactly the same hardware with no changes whatsoever.

**EDIT** Downloading and using the latest Windows 10 ISO and signing in using my Live account solved the problem.

Comment: While linking with your Microsoft account solved your problem, I wonder how this is solved for people who don't sign in with a Microsoft account.

Comment: Well, I'm guessing it just pulled the product key from my account online. I bet had I not had a Live account it would have let me enter the key manually.

Comment: Seems like typical Micrsooft to essentially force you to log in with your Microsoft account again to license Windows. I can't see why it would be so complicated to put a flag on the product key their end to 1) prevent confusion and 2) allow install without signing back in with Microsoft account.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need a product key to reinstall Windows 10 on an upgraded device. You have a digital license which will be activated online after installation. Skip the step that asks you to enter the product key.

> How you activate Windows 10 after reinstalling it depends on how Windows 10 was originally installed on your device.
>
> If you activated a free upgrade to Windows 10 or bought and activated
> Windows 10 from the Windows Store, you have a digital license for your
> device. This means you can reinstall the same edition of Windows 10
> that your device has a digital license for without entering a product
> key. During reinstallation, if you’re asked to enter a product key,
> you can skip this step. Windows 10 will automatically activate online
> after the installation is complete.

Source: https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/12440/windows-10-activation

Answer (score 0):

You need to re-install Windows 8.1 and then you'll be able to re-apply the Windows 10 upgrade.

Your Windows 8.1 key is not a valid Windows 10 key because it's a Windows 8.1 key - quite simple really :)

Comment: I actually tried that. I reinstalled and activated Windows 8.1, and then I tried upgrading to Windows 10 (both by running the setup while running Windows 8.1 AND by booting into the flash drive), and I get the same error about the product key being invalid for Windows 10.

Comment: You odn't use your product key for Windows 10 - at all. You install Windows 8.1 -> enter product key/activate -> install Windows 10 through the update

Comment: I was actually able to do a clean Windows 10 install without having Windows 8.1 installed. I skipped entering the key, used the latest ISO, signed in using my Live account, and Windows was activated automatically.